# Any source for a visualized SHA-2?

Tags: mining-theory, hash

Is there any source that visualizes how SHA-2 works (including internals) with animated video or an interactive web page?

Answer (score 3):

you can check this repo, iti si creedt for **Cryptography For Developers, Simon Johnson (pg. 218)**:
https://github.com/in3rsha/sha256-animation

Answer (score 2):

This shows an animation of the steps involved in computing a SHA2 hash.

https://youtu.be/FZeLKrQTZtE?t=84

I can't find a diagram of message expansion, but this shows a diagram of one round (SHA256 has 64 rounds):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2#/media/File:SHA-2.svg

Comment: Yes, it shows the numbers involved and how they changed. But I was looking for something more visual. Representing the changes in the placement of each word after each step, functions involved in each step, ... .

Comment: @mahdix Does the edit help?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [CrypTool 2](https://www.cryptool.org/en/ct2/downloads) (CT2). It is an open-source program offering an innovative visual programming GUI to experiment with cryptographic procedures and to animate their cascades.

Comment: This is an interesting tool, but does not let you see the internals of the hash, only inputs and outputs.

Comment: @bigjosh You mean like this? https://www.cryptool.org/en/cto/aes-animation

Comment: That is cool, but seems to be AES and not SHA-2.